# Why does tf.keras.models.Sequential give a different accuracy after evaluate() when compared to sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am training a binary classifier using tf.keras with the following setup:

Tensorflow 2.0 - GPU, Jupyter Notebook running Python 3.6

When I train my model I receive a reported accuracy of about 83% for my training data. I then evaluate the model with my test data and also receive an accuracy of about 83%. However, if I create a classification matrix with sklearn and calculate the accuracy that way, I receive an accuracy of about 68%.

Is tf.keras calculating accuracy differently from the expected approach:(correct classifications / total classifications) * 100% ???

Here is my relevant code and corresponding output:

```
train_df = df_to_dataset(X_train, y_train, shuffle=True, batch_size=10)
test_df = df_to_dataset(X_test, y_test, shuffle=True, batch_size=10)

lfc = len(feat_cols)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feat_cols),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(lfc, input_dim=lfc, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2*lfc, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2*lfc, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(lfc, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_df, epochs=15)

score = model.evaluate(test_df)

preds = model.predict(test_df)
y_pred = [1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in preds]
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(matrix)
accuracy = (matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1]) / (matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[1][1])
print("Accuracy: " + str(accuracy * 100) + "%")
```

[tf.keras output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92N89.png)

[sklearn.classification_matrix output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVMF2.png)

Comment: Why do you have the line 'y_pred = [1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in preds]'? If you are using binary_crossentropy it should do this for you

Comment: Because model.predict() seems to return probabilities instead of a binary output. I also thought this was strange and would open for suggestions on how to get the binary output directly (aside from my original question).